# Install ffserver on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: mac, operating-systems

I would like to install ffserver and got ffmpeg running on Mac OS X 10.6.
But for some reason I cant find a good tutorial to install ffserver on Mac OS X.
Does it come with ffmpeg ?
Is it outdated? Is there only one version that includes it and I dont know it ?

I really need to make this work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg comes with FFserver, so that shouldn't be the problem. You can manually compile it by downloading it from the [FFmpeg website](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Another easier option would be to use a package manager which automatically does that for you. I always suggest [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), which is really easy to use.

- You might want to install Xcode first. On Snow Leopard, register with [Apple Connect](http://connect.apple.com/) and [download it](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792).
- Run the following to install Homebrew

  ```
  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
  ```
- Wait a bit
- Then, install `ffmpeg` by running

  ```
  brew install ffmpeg
  ```
- Wait a bit (this may take a while, since it's downloading and building all dependencies)
- Finally, run `ffserver`, which will be in:

  ```
  /usr/local/bin/ffserver
  ```

[image]

Comment: A.W.E.S.O.M.E. Thanks a million. Homebrew rules ! It has a couple of errors where i need to link: the linking step did not complete successfully. ln: value.h Permission denied Do you know how to do this ? Thanks again

Comment: You can try to run `brew doctor` and see what it suggests. This is probably due to other installations. `sudo link ...` should also do, but it would be best to fix the permissions first.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of installing stable (but not latest) version would be

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Follow the on-screen instructions. This will take a few minutes while it's installing the necessary developer tools for OS X. Then run:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

More details @https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX